# Why does React dev tools show my component as Anonymous?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React dev tools works perfectly (properly shows the name of the component in components tab) when you have something like:

```
const MyComponent = ...
export { MyComponent }
```

But if you change it to inline exporting:

```
export const MyComponent = ...
```

it displays the component name as Anonymous.

Is something wrong with inline exporting in general?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For inline exporting you need to manually specify the displayName property (I know, it's a pain).

So you do

```
    export const MyComponent = () => {
      //stuff happens here
    }

    MyComponent.displayName = "MyComponent";
```

Comment: I think `export function MyComponent() {` works, the linter usually complains when you do `const MyPureComponent= React.memo(()=>{` but `cosnt MyPureComponent = React.memo(function MyPureComponent() {` will fix that.

Comment: Got it, but it definitely looks like an issue for dev tools, do you think so?

Answer (score 1):

If it's still not resolved as it wasn't for me, I found a workaround, I added -

```
devtool: 'eval-cheap-module-source-map'
```

to my `webpack.config.js` and make sure to start the webpack build after adding the property.

Before adding the devtool.
[image: Before]

After adding the devtool.
[image: After]

source: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/